# Unknown connection type of HDD

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I recently decided to upgrade my old laptop. I wanted to start with HDD. When I opened I saw that there was 2.5 inch Toshiba MK4025GAS HDD. My question is what connection type is this HDD. I looked in the internet but I won't found. If you know I will be happy to know.

Comment: -1 ”I looked in the internet but I won't found.” I just did a quick Google search for [MK4025GAS](https://www.google.com/search?q=MK4025GAS&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and 21,700+ results and clicking on the [first Amazon link](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00012BDDA) shows “Hard Disk Interface: IDE”. This is a very easy to self-answer question.

Comment: .. & now you know the answer, the next question will be "How do I get an SSD for it?" The answer to that will be, "You don't" Send the computer to recycle & don't waste any money on it. [Sorry - cruel, but fair]

Comment: @Tetsujin Just googling [IDE SSD](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ide+ssd) gets a few easy products... https://www.amazon.co.uk/128GB-KingSpec-2-5-inch-SM2236-Controller/dp/B0091T4ZWU Granted the capacity seems to be far lower and the price far higher than SATA for any given capacity, but for an ancient laptop to upgrade it might be fine, especially for older/smaller OS'es. But I do agree that drive performance is probably not the limiting factor for an old machine and this is a trivial question to answer just by Googling the drive part number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Mokubai - yeah… but 85 quid for a 128GB… & I'd read the warnings in the reviews below :(

Answer (score 2):

That is old PATA = IDE connector.

Answer (score 2):

#### What connection type is this HDD?

> Ultra-ATA/100

Source: [Hard Disk Sentinel - Technical details for disk TOSHIBA MK4025GAS](https://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=en&model=TOSHIBA%20MK4025GAS)